# I need to connect my project repo to common repo to work local

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github

I have two repos one is common component repo and one is separate project repo I have connected this repo in GitHub using in package JSON whatever I change in my common repo I have to create a build file and push it on GitHub every time I will do this then I can see a change in my septate repo by `npm i` but what my task is if I need to test something that I am doing in my common component I need to do that step to check changes but its make my work too hard to do everything this step I need to set like whatever I am changing in my common component that I am able to test locally by connecting to the common component repo so anyway can I connect like something symbolic like or any what that make this step smooth.
I have connected my common component repo like this in package.json

```
 "@common": "git+https://dev-user:ghp_RT5nojYRmTJgewvHNEB4JZiMwYktFh3MOTOu@github.com/Dev-Org/dev-frontend-common.git",
```

Comment: In Python I solve this situation by doing an editable install of the package so it gets run from my sandbox directly, with `pip install -e .`. There must be an equivalent option with `npm i`, as this is a very common use case.

Comment: but how can I do it in a locality I know I can use npm I but I need to push my code in git hub

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your question. I thought you wanted to be able to test locally without having to push the build file every time. Obviously I don't understand your workflow well enough to help, so hopefully someone else can help you. If you can rephrase your question to make it clearer, though, it might help.

Comment: i need to test locally without having to push the build file every time